# Azure Powershell Keyvaults - Returning Multiple SecretValueText returns null

Tags: powershell, azure

So to get a single secret from a vault and read it's secretValueText I can do this:

```
$kvSecret= Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certName
Write-Host($kvSecret.SecretValueText)
```

And it'll return the secret text e.g:

```
MIIJuQIBAzCCCX8GCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCCXAEgglsMIIJaDCCA/4GCSqGSIb3DQ...
```

But if I want to programmatically do this with all secrets in the vault I would do:

```
$kvSecret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName
$kvSecret | ForEach-Object {Write-Host($_.SecretValueText)}
```

When I try to iterate through them and get the SecretValueText this time they return as null. Using a ForEach loop yields the same result too.

Comment: I test in my lab many times. It seems that it is not possible. I get the same result with you return null. I could get other information such as vault name,  secret name in the loop, but could not get the `SecretValueText`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lost `-Name $certName` in your code below. It should be like this:

```
$kvSecret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certname
$kvSecret | ForEach-Object {Write-Host($_.SecretValueText)}
```

If these is no `-Name` after `get-AzureKeyVaultSecret`, the class you got is `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.SecretIdentityItem`, not `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.Secret`. Ther is no property called `SecretValueText` in `Microsoft.***.SecretIdentityItem`. If you want to get all secrets in you vault, try this:

```
$myVault = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName
$myVault | ForEach-Object {Write-Host(get-azureKeyVaultSecret -vaultName $_.vaultName -name $_.Name).SecretValueText}
```

Comment: Hi, the idea for doing that was to to get all the secrets from the vault. Is that not the correct way?

Comment: Thanks this is what I ended up doing, marked as solved